# iAd not showing on user devices but showing on my Xcode deployed device

Tags: ios, iad, adbannerview

I made an application that only supports landscape mode and it includes an iAd banner. The banner is showing on my development device just fine, banner with message "You're connected to iAd network".

My application received around 100 downloads its first day on the App Store but not one iAd banner request. I downloaded my application from the App Store and still received the "You're connected to iAd network" message. I downloaded the application from a non development device and iAd does not appear at all.

Is there an issue with my implementation?

**.h**

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface `enter code here`ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,ADBannerViewDelegate>
{

    BOOL _bannerIsVisible;
ADBannerView *_adBanner;
```

**.m**

```
- (void)iAdInit:(BOOL) isInit {
    int width;
    int height;

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"removeAd"]!=1)
    {
        if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
                width=1024;
                height=66;
        }
        else//iphone or ipad
        {
                width=480;
                height=32;
        }

        if(isInit)
        {
            _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
            _adBanner.delegate = self;
            [_adBanner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, width,height)];
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self iAdInit:1];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"Load AD");
    if (!_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        // If banner isn't part of view hierarchy, add it
        if (_adBanner.superview == nil)
        {
            [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
        }
        banner.hidden=NO;

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        [self moveOverBannerElements:-banner.frame.size.height];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Can't Load AD");

    if (_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [self moveOverBannerElements:banner.frame.size.height];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            banner.hidden=YES;
        });

        _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint2;

-(void)moveOverBannerElements:(float) offsetYPosition {
    if(constraint){[self.view removeConstraint: constraint];}
    if(constraint2){[self.view removeConstraint: constraint2];}

    if(offsetYPosition<0){
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resolutionSegment attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:offsetYPosition-4];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fpsSegment attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:offsetYPosition-4];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];
    }
}
-(void) removeAd {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"removeAd"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    ///return elements to defaul position
    if(constraint){[self.view removeConstraint: constraint];}
    if(constraint2){[self.view removeConstraint: constraint2];}
    ///return elements to defaul position

    _adBanner.hidden=YES;
    NSLog(@"remove ad");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your application has been approved and released on the App Store it will be reviewed by the iAd Network team. Once they approve, ads will be delivered to your application. This can sometimes take up to 7 business days.

If you're receiving the blue *You're Connected To iAd* advertisements when testing your application then you're good to go.

---

From the [Contact Us](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/115.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1) page:
<sub><sup>(iAd App Network>General iAd App Network Questions>Joining the iAd App Network)</sup></sub>

> After your app has been approved and is in the Ready for Sale state, it also will be reviewed by iAd to determine the app’s appropriateness for receiving ads from iAd advertisers. After your app has been approved by iAd, you can start earning revenue for ads that run in your app.